# Why can I not save images in a loop?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to save images in loop with different names. My code is executing without error but the files are not being saved. It is though showing a warning.

```
y1   = linspace(0.51,0.61,0.01,endpoint=True)
y2   = linspace(0.52,0.62,0.01,endpoint=True)
name = linspace(1,11,1,endpoint=True)

for i,j,k in zip(y1,y2,name):

    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    A = (a**2)*sin(p)*sqrt(1-sin(p)*sin(p))
    B = (a*b*d)/(sin(p)**2)
    C = a*b*d
    D = a*c*sqrt(1-sin(p)*sin(p))
    E = a*c*sin(p)*sqrt(1-sin(p)*sin(p))
    F = (b*c*d)/(sin(p)**3)
    G = (b*c*d)/sin(p)

    H = a*d* (   (a/(sin(p)*sin(p))) - a + (c/(sin(p)**3)) - (c/(sin(p))) )

    t = abs((A+B-C+D+E+F-G) / (H))

    ax.scatter(angle_degrees,t)
    ax.xlim(0,-90)
    ax.ylim(i,j)
    ax.set_xlabel('Angle', fontsize=16)
    ax.set_ylabel('Time', fontsize=16)
    ax.set_title('Formula 1', fontsize=16)
    plt.savefig('A{}.png'.format(k))
```

I can not understand what the problem is. Although there is a warning

```
DeprecationWarning: object of type <class 'float'> cannot be
safely interpreted as an integer.
app.launch_new_instance()
```

Comment: Where did you create the figure? You should create a new figure every time you loop.

Comment: Interesting, perhaps add some debugging messages to see where it fails

Comment: I tried that but did not work too. updated code @BenT

Comment: Your use of linspace looks wrong. Check those arrays.  Print the file name before you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it this time. The arguments in **linspace** were wrong. I was treating it as **arange**. My bad. Here is the right code:

```
y1   = linspace(0.51,0.61,10,endpoint=True)
y2   = linspace(0.52,0.62,10,endpoint=True)
name = linspace(1,11,10,endpoint=True)

for i,j,k in zip(y1,y2,name):

    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    A = (a**2)*sin(p)*sqrt(1-sin(p)*sin(p))
    B = (a*b*d)/(sin(p)**2)
    C = a*b*d
    D = a*c*sqrt(1-sin(p)*sin(p))
    E = a*c*sin(p)*sqrt(1-sin(p)*sin(p))
    F = (b*c*d)/(sin(p)**3)
    G = (b*c*d)/sin(p)

    H = a*d* (   (a/(sin(p)*sin(p))) - a + (c/(sin(p)**3)) - (c/(sin(p))) )

    t = abs((A+B-C+D+E+F-G) / (H))

    ax.scatter(angle_degrees,t)
    ax.xlim(0,-90)
    ax.ylim(i,j)
    ax.set_xlabel('Angle', fontsize=16)
    ax.set_ylabel('Time', fontsize=16)
    ax.set_title('Formula 1', fontsize=16)
    plt.savefig('A{}.png'.format(k))
```

Thanks for your comments guyz.